# Folder Share permissions

Tags: windows, permissions

I am having a weird issue that didn't used to happen.  Perhaps windows update causes this?

We have an E drive partition created and I created a directory:
Test1

I shared it with administrators and everyone.  Administrators have full access while everyone group only has read permissions but this folder only. I added a permission  to allow full control to this folder and subfolder's and files to it and assigned it to domain admins.  My jadmin@domain.local account is added to this group
I checked the security on the folder and the same permissions exist.
I created a directory within Test1 and called it New Folder, disabled inheritance and made sure explicit permissions for domain admins full control to all dir and subdir and files are added.
When i attempt to open this folder, i get a message:
"You don't currently have permission to access this folder.  Click Continue to permanently get access to this folder".

When I Push Continue then an explicit permission for my user gets added to that folder.  I am trying to prevent that from happening.  If domain admins(my user added to this group) is added with full control.  Why does this warning pop up and require my user to explicitly be added.  How to prevent this from occurring?

I was expecting to be able to access the new folder directory without any warning and an explicit permission to be added

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can access it with an elevated CMD.

Folders wich are protected for builtin administrators groups are supposed to be security relevant. These users should also not be used to administrate on server systems.

Increase security by creating a seperate admin group and dedicated permissions.

Alternatives are using a progam that can be started elevated, Like CMD, PowerShell, totalCommander, winscp (local part) and many more.

You could also administrate remote. That should remove the problem.

Another way would be to add "Interactive Logon" group to all of your permissions where you need to access.

Disabling UAC or removing administrators from the security settings is the least that I would suggest.

Comment: Sorry for the long wait.  When i access via cmd with elevated privs, it can access.  When I access via cmd without elevation, i cannot access.  I was thinking of allowing interactive login in the permissions but that seems to allow anyone who wouldnt normally have access to the files if they were able to get physical access to the machine.  Luckily its a vm and we disabled remote access for ordinary users.

Comment: Is there a way to allow all domain admins to access a folder?  Here's what the folder looks like:

Specific department group has full control.  this folder and subfolder/files
System: Full control - this folder and subfolder/files
Everyone: Read Permissions for this folder only
Domain Admins - Full Control this folder and subfolder/files

Comment: As soon as you add read only for authenticated users then domain admins users can get into that folder without any issues and those warnings posted above.  Once you remove that permission then same thing occurs. Domain admins permissions should have access to the folder because it is explicit permissions to it.  Why does adding authenticated users or modifing everyone permissions affect domain admins access?  It should already have it because its listed as full control.

Comment: In addition, I created a separate security group and added individual domain admins to it and then added that group to the folder as full control.  Same issue